# How to have ticks on x axis in 15 min increments on chartJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

So my current chart has incremental steps of random times.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzlyT.png)

I would like it so that it is broken up into 15 mins increments (i.e. 12:45, 13:00, 13:15, 13:30...)

This is how i currently have the ticks setting:

```
        ticks: {
          color: theme.colors.primary,
          padding: 2,
          maxTicksLimit: 6,
          autoSkip: true,
          maxRotation: 0,
          minRotation: 0,
          labelOffset: 25,
        },
```

This is the current data coming in for the date/time:

```
[
  1645484400, 1645486200, 1645488000, 1645489800, 1645491600,
  1645493400, 1645495200, 1645497000, 1645498800, 1645500600,
  1645502400, 1645504200, 1645506000, 1645507800, 1645509600,
  1645511400, 1645513200, 1645515000, 1645516800, 1645518600,
  1645520400, 1645522200, 1645524000, 1645525800, 1645527600,
  1645529400, 1645531200, 1645533000, 1645534800, 1645536600,
  1645538400, 1645540200, 1645542000, 1645543800, 1645545600,
  1645547400, 1645549200, 1645551000, 1645552800, 1645554600,
  1645556400, 1645558200, 1645560000, 1645561800, 1645563600,
  1645565400, 1645567200, 1645569000, 1645570800, 1645572600,
  1645574400, 1645576200, 1645578000, 1645579800, 1645581600,
  1645583400, 1645585200, 1645587000, 1645588800, 1645590600,
  1645592400, 1645594200, 1645596000, 1645597800, 1645599600,
  1645601400, 1645603200, 1645605000, 1645606800, 1645608600,
  1645610400, 1645612200, 1645614000, 1645615800, 1645617600,
  1645619400, 1645621200, 1645623000, 1645624800, 1645626600,
  1645628400, 1645630200, 1645632000, 1645633800, 1645635600,
  1645637400, 1645639200, 1645641000, 1645642800, 1645644600,
  1645646400, 1645648200, 1645650000, 1645651800, 1645653600,
  1645655400, 1645657200, 1645659000, 1645660800, 1645662600,
  ... 1339 more items
]
```

Any idea what would be the best way to execute this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [timeseries](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/timeseries.html) to spread the points on the axis equidistantly